# Custom template page for several permalinks wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates

I built a custom template page named Single Listing. permalink for this page is / homes /

[image]

But I'd like to show this custom template page for all the urls formatted like this homes/*

I am new to wordpress so any help or suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `homes` a page and you woul like to show it's child pages with the same custom template? if so: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130971/load-child-template-based-on-parent

Comment: @caiovisk Sorry, it didn't help me. Maybe I did do wrong steps or my issue explanation was incorrect. And yes, I'd like to show same template for all the urls `localhost:8888/homes/* ` not just for `localhost:8888/homes`

Comment: @Prodev525 The same solution would apply to your problem. But you need to update your condition for URL patterns instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this might be helpful for you.

```php
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {
   global $wp;
   $current_url_path =  home_url( $wp->request );
   $url_pattern = '/(^homes[\/\w]*)/gim'

   if ( is_page()  && preg_match($pattern, $current_url_path)) {
      $new_template = locate_template( array( 'home-page-template.php' ) );

      if ( '' != $new_template ) {
         return $new_template ;
      }
   }

   return $template;
}
```